# window.innerHeight is working but $(window).innerHeight() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery 2.0.3

**Problem:**

`$(window).innerHeight()` returns zero.

But `window.innerHeight` returns correct height.

Same behaviour in console.

*This problem exists only in Firefox. No problem in Chrome and Safari. I tried to fresh load the site many times but still problem persists.*

**What I've tried:**
I checked for a `div.menubar` height with `$(".menubar").innerHeight()` in console - it returns correct value.

I checked the `$(window)` object in JS using "inspect element" by placing breakpoint after this line. The `$(window)` has the url of my webpage so it refers to the correct window.

Comment: can  u give us a fiddle so that we'll know the exact reason

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/dimensions-window-innerHeight-in-Firefox-throws-exception-td140656.html

Second answer - **There is no innerheight for window, only height** :)

Answer (score 0):

never expected this would be the problem
thanks to the reply to the "thought to be bug" : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13333

the bug was closed with a comment that "judging by the code snippet you're in quirks mode"

So then i immediately checked for  in my html, it wasnt there so after adding it everything works perfect

Thanks guys for helping me

Answer (score 0):

This method returns the height of the element, including top and bottom padding, in pixels.

This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .height() instead.